# Is Coca Cola (and other beverages) kosher everywhere in the world?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I'm currently sitting in an airport transit lounge in Istanbul, and thinking I wouldn't half mind a drink.  Available to me are the usual range: Coke, Fanta, Sprite, filter coffee...

Are these beverages kosher all around the world, or only where there is a kosher certification authority?  And if the latter, does anyone have any specific information about which ones are kosher in Turkey?  I found the Turkish kashrus authority's [website](http://www.denetgida.com.tr/), but it doesn't contain any kosher product guides, so far as I could tell...

Comment: +1 for "I'm currently sitting in an airport transit lounge in Istanbul"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see below the link from Kosharot, an orthodox kasrus organization from Elon Moreh, Israel. 
They claim that Rabbi Moshe Leib Landau, the hashgacha of Coca Cola in Israel (and may know the secret formula), says that you can't assume that it is kosher all around the world, but you need a kosher certification.

http://www.kosharot.co.il/ask_show.asp?id=4435 (hebrew)

**EDIT:**

There is a new discussion in Israel regarding the kashrut of the Coke from the Palestinian Authority. The hashgacha of the Chief Rabbinate of Israel says that it is not kosher since there is no hashgacha, but the OU says that the Coke is kosher since (as was mentioned by Ariel) the flavor is Kosher (hashgacha of OU in US) and the locals add only sugar and water.

See the following link (hebrew):

http://www.srugim.co.il/46727-%D7%94-ou-%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%93%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%94-%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%A1

Comment: Wow, that's an eye opener.  Thanks!

Comment: Moreover, he says that Coke is kosher only in Israel. He says that he got Coke to change their secret ingredient for him.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin He says also the US and possibly the UK.

Comment: Coke has been kosher for nearly a century in America. See this article by the Chemical Heritage Foundation: http://www.chemheritage.org/discover/media/magazine/articles/30-3-the-real-thing-how-coke-became-kosher.aspx?page=1

Comment: @DoubleAA he doesn't say, the website says that part " הרב לנדאו נותן כשרות על קוקה קולה כאן בארץ ואומרים שהוא אחד מהיחידים בעולם שיודע את "סוד" המתכון של הקוקה קולה. נאמר לי שא"א לסמוך על מה שאומרים שבכל העולם המוצר הוא אותו דבר בדיוק. אלא אפשר לשתות רק היכן שיש הכשר כגון בארץ או הכשר o-u בארה"ב ." note that *נאמר לי* which doesn't say exactly *who* told it to him (with no evidence it was Rabbi Landau)

Answer (score 6):

This is only a partial answer, but since you have not gotten any other answer I'll post it.

The basic flavor of Coca Cola is made only in the US and shipped throughout the world (and is Kosher). Each local area adds sweeteners, water, and CO2.

The process is pretty automated and is probably free of any contaminants, but the source of the sweetener can be a kashrus issue. Also if the factory make any other lines of beverages - particularly those made with carmine (which is still used) it can be an issue (however it's probably batel).

Do you need a hechsher for sugar in Turkey? In the US you don't, but things may be different elsewhere. Same for corn syrup.

Best bet is to call the local kashrus agency.

(Also this answer does not address other brands which I have not researched.)

Comment: I liked the Coca Cola process...where did u learn from?